# Single click hides other content

Tags: javascript, jquery

If Button One is clicked the **Content** is visible and when Button Two is clicked that **Content** is visible.
  Here's what needs to happen:
  Button One is clicked and the **Content** is visible then Button Two is clicked and Button One **Content** is hidden while Button Two **Content** is visible and vise versa.
In other words, Button One and Button Two **Content cannot** be visible at the same time.

`You can find the code at:`[jsfiddle.net/4HYcX/97/](http://jsfiddle.net/4HYcX/97/)

This is the code on jsfiddle:

```
.interactContainers {
    display:none;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

function toggleInteractContainers(x) {
    if ($('#'+x).is(":hidden")) {
        $('#'+x).slideDown(200);
    } else {
        $('#'+x).hide();
    }
    $('.interactContainers').hide();
}

<a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="toggleInteractContainers('one');">Button One</a>  
<div class="interactContainers" id="one">
    Content for Button One. <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="toggleInteractContainers('one');" title="Close">Exit</a>
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="toggleInteractContainers('two');">Button Two</a>
<div class="interactContainers" id="two">
    Content for Button Two. <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="toggleInteractContainers('two');" title="Close">Exit</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your code here and don't try to get around SO rules.  They are there for a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slide up anything that isn't the current clicked element:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/4HYcX/103/)

```
function toggleInteractContainers(x) {
    $('.interactContainers').not('#' + x).slideUp(200);
    if ($('#' + x).is(":hidden")) {
        $('#' + x).slideDown(200);
    } else {
        $('#' + x).slideUp(); // <== also changed to slideUp instead of hide
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all the excellent suggestions. It's so simple I could not see it. Thanks again to everyone for the quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'd want to use an [accordion widget](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) from jQuery UI. At least it looks like that's what you're trying to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Add `$('.interactContainers').not('#' + x).hide();` to the first line of your `toggleInteractContainers` function. This hides all `div` elements with the class `interactContainers` apart from the one you are going to open (`x`).

```
function toggleInteractContainers(x) {
    // Hide all apart from the one about to be opened.
    $('.interactContainers').not('#' + x).hide();
    if ($('#' + x).is(":hidden")) {
        $('#' + x).slideDown(200);
    } else {
        $('#' + x).hide();
    }
    //if $('.interactContainers').hide(); is commented out it's a single click but the Content for the buttons stay open when each is clicked.
    //$('.interactContainers').hide();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4HYcX/100/

Comment: Is there a reason not to hide the one that's about to be shown? Also, if the one being clicked is to be hidden, and you hide all at the beginning, you could get rid of the else entirely.

Comment: No, this way you are creating a toggle effect. If you remove the `not(..` line, you won't be able to do that.

Comment: Oh right. It works in mine because I put it inside the if, but here it wouldn't because it's before.

Answer (score 0):

It's not especially pretty, but you can just hide all `.interactContainers` before showing the one you want to show:
http://jsfiddle.net/4HYcX/97/

Answer (score 0):

You updated code:
Button One and Button Two need to function with a single click.

```
<div style="color:red">Content for Button One and Button Two should not be open at the same time.</div>
  <br />
  <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="toggleInteractContainers('one','two');">Button One</a>
  <div class="interactContainers" id="one">
      <span style="color:red">Content</span> for Button One. <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="toggleInteractContainers('one','two');" title="Close">Exit</a>
    </div>
  <br />
  <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="toggleInteractContainers('two','one');">Button Two</a>
  <div class="interactContainers" id="two">
        <span style="color:red">Content</span> for Button Two. <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="toggleInteractContainers('two','one');" title="Close">Exit</a>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
function toggleInteractContainers(x,y) {
        if ($('#'+x).is(":hidden")) {
            $('#'+x).slideDown(200);
            $('#'+y).hide();
        } else {
            $('#'+x).hide();
            $('#'+y).slideDown(200);
        }
    //if $('.interactContainers').hide(); is commented out it's a single click but the Content for the buttons stay open when each is clicked.
        //$('.interactContainers').hide();
    }
```